# Can I clamp a value into a range in Ada?

Tags: ada

Is there a nice way to clamp (clip?, coerce?) a value to a range in Ada?
I have done that for now:

```
timer := Integer'Max(timer, Integer(Half_Word'First));
timer := Integer'Min(timer, Integer(Half_Word'Last));
TIM8.TIM.ARR := Half_Word(timer);
```

But this is a bit clunky, I'd like to clamp the variable timer into the range of Half_Word.

Comment: Could you just declare `timer : Half_Word;`? -- that way you’d have to get the calculation right in the first place.

Comment: What type is the timer ? (Why cant you use Half_word as your timer type?)

Comment: timer is Integer, I'm clamping *before* passing the value into a Half_Word, because I absolutely do not want it to wrap. timer comes from computations involving huge numbers (clock frequencies, clock dividers etc.), so I can't do the computation in Half_Word.

Comment: All: I do not understand why people are assuming the questioner doesn't know what he really wants.  Couldn't we start by assuming that the questioner knows more about the task he's trying to accomplish than the rest of us do?  I can understand that newbies often come up with inferior solutions and need to be given some new ideas.  But as a non-newbie, when I've asked a question and someone else assumed they knew what my purposes were and told me "Why don't you just do WXYZ instead", I've found it quite insulting.

Comment: I tend to agree with AJB on that one. I have an encoder to drive the speed of a motor. It's out of question that the next speed after the fastest be stopping. But it's perfectly acceptable that when you try to get higher than the max speed, you just get the max speed. And I do it at the last stage, so that even if I send the speed by software and make mistake, it will be clamped and not wrapped.

Comment: a *timer* is a device that has a *counter* and and auto reload register (and, in this instance, 18 other registers and 67 pages of obscure documentation). So I used the word counter for *auto reload register* because it an irrelevant detail and it's not my question and I don't even see how that could influence the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use defaults to make this a bit easier to use -- the biggest problem [maintenance-wise] then is that it looks like there's more going on than there really is, and the biggest drawback to this is that the constraint of `DESTINATION_TYPE` being a subset of `SOURCE_TYPE` is not checked/enforced at compile-time by the compiler.

```ada
generic
  type Source_Type is range <>;
  type Destination_Type is range <>;

  S_First : Long_Long_Integer:= Long_Long_Integer(Source_Type'First);     --' FIX FOR
  S_Last  : Long_Long_Integer:= Long_Long_Integer(Source_Type'Last);      --' BUGGY 
  D_First : Long_Long_Integer:= Long_Long_Integer(Destination_Type'First);--' SYNTAX
  D_Last  : Long_Long_Integer:= Long_Long_Integer(Destination_Type'Last); --' HIGHLIGHT.
function Saturate (X : Source_Type) return Destination_Type
 with Pre => 
          D_First >= S_First
      and D_Last  <= S_Last;

function Saturate (X : Source_Type) return Destination_Type is
  X_Pos : constant Long_Long_Integer:= Long_Long_Integer(X);
begin      
  if X_Pos in D_First..D_Last then
     return Destination_Type(X);
  elsif X_Pos < D_First then
     return Destination_Type'First; --'
  else
     return Destination_Type'Last;  --'
  end if;
end Saturate;
```

Example usage:

```ada
subtype K is Integer range 2..24;
subtype J is Integer range 3..10;

Function P is new Saturate(Source_Type      => K,
                           Destination_Type => J
                          );
```

Comment: thanks, this calls 2 questions:1) what's the link between modular types and range types? 2) is there a way to use the function in one line (generic instantiation and function call in one expression)?

Comment: I'm not sure on (1); no for (2) -- because the defining of the function, the instantiation, is separate from the call itself.

Answer (score 5):

Ada does not have a built-in way to do this.  If this is the kind of thing you will be doing repeatedly, and on different types, a generic like this might help:

```
generic
     type Source_Type is range <>;
     type Destination_Type is range <>;
function Saturate (X : Source_Type) return Destination_Type;

function Saturate (X : Source_Type) return Destination_Type is
    Result : Source_Type;
begin
    Result := Source_Type'Max (X, Source_Type (Destination_Type'First));
    Result := Source_Type'Min (Result, Source_Type (Destination_Type'Last));
    return Destination_Type (Result);
end Saturate; 

...

function Saturate_To_Half_Word is new Saturate (Integer, Half_Word); 

... 

TIM8.TIM.ARR := Saturate_To_Half_Word(timer);
```

**EDIT:** The above assumes that the bounds of `Destination_Type` will always be included in `Source_Type`.  The code will raise a `Constraint_Error` if this is not the case.  An alternative that will work even if `Destination_Type` could be larger than `Source_Type`:

```
function Saturate (X : Source_Type) return Destination_Type is
    type Largest_Int is range System.Min_Int .. System.Max_Int;
    Result : Source_Type;
begin
    Result := X;
    if Largest_Int (Destination_Type'First) in
         Largest_Int (Source_Type'First) .. Largest_Int (Source_Type'Last) then
        Result := Source_Type'Max (Result, Source_Type (Destination_Type'First));
    end if;
    if Largest_Int (Destination_Type'Last) in
         Largest_Int (Source_Type'First) .. Largest_Int (Source_Type'Last) then
        Result := Source_Type'Min (Result, Source_Type (Destination_Type'Last));
    end if;
    return Destination_Type (Result);
end Saturate;
```

You have to code it carefully to avoid type conflicts but also avoid raising `Constraint_Error`.

**EDIT 2:** I had `First` and `Last` backwards.  Fixed.

**EDIT 3:** Following Simon's suggestion, this will also work:

```
function Saturate (X : Source_Type) return Destination_Type is
    type Largest_Int is range System.Min_Int .. System.Max_Int;
    Result : Largest_Int;
begin
    Result := Largest_Int (X);
    Result := Largest_Int'Max (Result, Largest_Int (Destination_Type'First));
    Result := Largest_Int'Min (Result, Largest_Int (Destination_Type'Last));
    return Destination_Type (Result);
end Saturate;
```

This looks simpler, but is potentially slightly less efficient because it involves more type conversions at run time.  (Note that the complex-looking conditions in the previous example are all conditions that can be evaluated at compile time and therefore should not generate any code--plus it could cause the `'Max` and/or `'Min` operations to be eliminated.  This is assuming the compiler uses a "macro expansion" model for generic instantiation, as GNAT does.  A really good compiler may be able to figure out the same kinds of optimizations in the latter code too, but it's harder.)

Comment: The source text in the answer does not compile, and fixing it isn't quite trivial.

Comment: Sorry, the arguments to `Source_Type'Max` and `'Min` need to be type-converted to `Source_Type`.  It should be OK now.  I broke it up because it was getting too messy to write in one line.

Comment: You might add a message to `Constraint_Error` in the function, reporting that `Destination_Type` should be a subset of `Source_Type` for the function to work.  (I can't see any other possible reasons for the function to raise a `Constraint_Error`.)

Comment: I think `’Max`, `’Min` are used the wrong way round. And it might be better to have `Result : Largest_Int;`. And, do you then really need the conditions?

Comment: @SimonWright You're right about `'Max` and `'Min`--fixed.  Blame it on Caffeine Deficiency Syndrome.  Also, you're right that it can be written without the conditions, but the conditions can be evaluated at compile time.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: Annoying that it can't be made clear and efficient at the same time. - One way of forcing `Destination_Type` to be a subset of `Source_Type` could be to make the generic a package; use `Source_Type`, `First` and `Last` as generic parameters; and then declare `subtype Destination_Type is Source_Type range First .. Last;` before declaring `function Saturate`. -- But this will not work if `Source_Type` and `Destination_Type` have to be distinct types.